# Request-promise + post+ mock

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using jest as Unit testing framework. I just tried to mock the **POST** method of **request-promise** library. But i am gettign error

**a.js** file:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
async abc(req, res){
const options = {      
      port: 8888,      
      body:data,
      url: 'http://url',
      method: 'POST',      
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'        
      }
    let response = await rp(options);
    console.log("rrreess", response);
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    }
});
```

**a.spec.ts**

```
jest.mock('request-promise', () => ({
    post: jest.fn()
  }));
const rp = require('request-promise');
jest.spyOn(rp, 'post').mockResolvedValue({            
        });
```

But i am receiving error **TypeError: rp is not a function** in a.js file. Is i am mocking correctly?

Comment: I'd recommend using e.g. [`msw`](https://mswjs.io/) rather than mocking out something you don't own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "**TypeError: rp is not a function**" happens because you're mocking `rp` as an object with a property `post` (a method).

```js
jest.mock('request-promise', () => ({ // Returns an object { post: jest.fn() }
    post: jest.fn()
}));
```

But you're definitely using it as a function by calling `rp(options)` instead of `rp.post(options)` here :

```
let response = await rp(options);
```

By the way, you're spying & mocking value of `rp.post` with :

```
jest.spyOn(rp, 'post').mockResolvedValue({});
```

I looks like `request-promise` is deprecated, but if you want your tests to pass, you can remove the spy on `rp.post` and replace your mock of `request-promise` by this one :

```
jest.mock('request-promise', () => jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({}));
```

Notice that it will return an empty object, but this should answer your question.